# Mobile Firefox development directly on my (rooted) Android instead of having to repack and reinstall the fennec APK for every little edit?

Tags: android, firefox, fennec

For mobile Firefox development, how can I hack the core javascript directly on my (rooted) Android so I can get instant results instead of having to repack and reinstall the fennec APK for every little edit ?

The problem is that all the files are locked up in the /data/app/org.mozilla.fennec/base.apk, and within that there is another archive (/asses/omni.ja) which can be unzipped to give the javascript. Reconstructing the apk file on device after editing the zip file inside it has proved unworkable, as although the apk file can be unzipped, it does not work when simply zipped back up again.

The goal is just to try things out and learn the workings of Firefox on device and on the go.

Answer (score 0):

Android install the app to a directory in /data/app/[package name]

You should be able to find the directory for this browser using the package name.

Then you can edit the javascript files in that folder but you might have to restart the app.

Comment: repackaging won't work on the device. but it sounds like it's an open source project, you can try to change the source and have the asset loaded from the filesystem instead.